# Stupid crash when setting collection cell frame

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

It might be something stupid and i am doing this for years, but i just cant figure this one out .

In my collection view cell class i have this :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.title.frame=CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);

}
```

the cells are ok only if i remove this line of the frame settings, if not, i get :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcbbd0afb0'
```

everything is set, and i didn't miss a thing, i already done that many times.
What is this ??

EDIT:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UILabel *title;
```

Comment: where are you doing this ? in collection cell class?

Comment: self.title is a NSString object, no UIView...

Comment: no its not. its a UILabel

Comment: first thing's first: what do you think what the `title`'s type is? it seem it is `NSString`, and `NSString` has no such selector like `setFrame:`... and that is your exception about precisely.

Comment: its a UILabel @property

Comment: More importantly, what class is this code in? What is the type of `self`? My guess is this in a view controller class.

Comment: its in UICollectionViewCell

Comment: @Curnelious, it must not be `UILabel`, because the exception clearly says to you it is an `NSString`.

Comment: i know ! :) but its not.... its really not. see my edit

Comment: Even though the property has type ```UILabel```, it is very likely that somewhere, you are setting it to an instance of ```NSString```.  Xcode only gives you a warning, not an error, if you try to do this.  Look at the Issue Navigator on the left-hand side of Xcode to see where this may be happening.

Comment: @Curnelious, it seems your runtime environment has a very strong second opinion about it, and unfortunately it is right... and you are not, because explicitly typecasting an `NSString` as `UILabel`does not change the actual object in the memory.

Comment: thanks all ! see my answer here- you where absolutely right !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh no... thanks to the help of the good people here, i found out  that i do this

```
cell.title=[dic objectForKey:@"title"];
```

instead of this

```
cell.title.text=[dic objectForKey:@"title"];
```

so it turned to a string ! (??)